# Change behavior of Control key on Ubuntu with Mac keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, mac, keyboard

On Ubuntu 10.10, is there any way to change the keyboard layout to where the <kbd>Command</kbd> key acts like the <kbd>Control</kbd> key?

And, if hardware makes any difference, I am on a 13" Aluminum Late '08 MacBook.

Comment: Ditto for 11.10

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that the Command key is the same as the Windows key (or Super) in Bootcamp/whatever.

1. Back up. Santa will thank you.
2. Read [this guide](http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/09/15/faq-how-to-disableremap-a-keyboard-key-in-linux/) and [this guide](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/how-do-i-remap-alt-to-a-super-key-696858/) if you want to get a basic idea of what I'm doing in step 3.
3. Add these two commands to your startup (System->Administration->Startup Applications):

   ```
   xmodmap -e 'keycode 133=Control_L'
   xmodmap -e 'keycode 37=Super_L'
   ```

   That'll take care of the left side, swapping the Command and Control key functions.
4. Add these two commands to your startup too for the right command and control.

   ```
   xmodmap -e 'keycode 134=Control_R'
   xmodmap -e 'keycode 109=Super_R'
   ```

It'll only work as soon as you log in though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try this as soon as I get the chance! (Computer is getting fixed x_x)

Comment: Hi, I tried this and it didn't work. The keys stay the same.

Comment: If you open a terminal and run any pair of commands does it work?

Comment: @digitxp: I tried that and that doesn't work, either.

Comment: Hm...that's tough. Does the Command key act like a Super key (quick way to check is to hit Cmd+E and again. If it works it'll show the multiple desktops view and return to normal view)

Comment: @digitxp: I tried that and it didn't work, so I guess the command key isn't working at all...

Comment: That could be it then.

Answer (score 1):

You can also set this in the GUI:

Go into System -> Preferences -> Keyboard

Click on the "Layouts" tab and then click the "Layout Options" button.

Click on "Alt/Win key behavior"

Select "Control is mapped to Win keys (and the usual ctrl key).

from
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1293081